# Cannot resolve keyword ‘data’ into field. Choices are: id, nome

Tags: django-rest-framework

Django Version: 4.1.2

Exception Type: FieldError

Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword ‘data’ into the field. Choices are: id, nome

Here are my codes

```py
#model
from django.db import models
class Teste(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

#serializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Teste

class TesteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Teste
    fields = '__all__'

#view
from .models import Teste
from .serializer import TesteSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser

@api_view(['POST'])
def create_teste(request):
    #data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    teste = Teste.objects.get(data = request.data)
    serializer = TesteSerializer(teste)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Hi, I'm trying to make an essay for `django_rest_framework` but I'm facing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access Teste model with `data` keyword but It is not belong to the Teste model. I don't know why you need to get Teste object for create.

Just remove `teste = Teste.objects.get(data = request.data)` this line and change `serializer = TesteSerializer(teste)` to `serializer = TesteSerializer(data=request.data)`

Answer (score 0):

`data` is not a field on the `Teste` model, so you cannot filter on it with:

```
Teste.objects.get(data=...)
```

You likely want to filter on `nome`, the name field of the model, with:

```
Teste.objects.get(nome=request.data['nome'])
```

That being said, a *GET* view usually does not create objects, so you should use `Teste.objects.filter(...)` here, and use a *POST* view to create objects.

Furthermore you should not use `.get(...)` here, since that will raise an exception if no object is found, or if multiple objects are found. Use `.filter(...)` to obtain a QuerySet, and then inspect the count to check if there is exactly one match.

Finally, you should not parse the request data yourself. Simply pass `request.data` to the serializer, and let the serializer parse the *JSON* data.

So a valid *POST* view would be:

```py
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_teste(request):
    serializer = TesteSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

And a valid *GET* view:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_teste(request):
    testes = Teste.objects.filter(nome=request.query_params.get('nome'))
    if testes.count() == 1:
        serializer = TesteSerializer(testes.get())
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        return Response({'detail': 'Teste not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Note that a *GET* view should return a *404* status in case the object is not found, not a *500* error.